# preg_replace to divide the data by extracting the last coincidence between square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I've a regular expresion for extract country on a string

Strings

```
BRY AIR PVT LTD [IN] 
BRY AIR [ASIA] PVT LTD [IN]
```

Latest substring between square brackets exists sometimes, and other times not.

If exists espace betwee last word and this substring is not a normal space. Is a invisible space.

Sometines as a incorrect aditional space at end

```
function extractNameAndCountry {
    $without = preg_replace('/[\W]*$/', '', preg_replace('/[\p{Z}\t]*(\[(.*?)\])?$/u', '', trim($string)));
    if (preg_match('/\[([^\)]*)\]/', $string, $matches)) {
        $country = $matches[1];
    }
}

extractNameAndCountry('BRY AIR PVT LTD [IN]');  
echo $without -> BRY AIR PVT LTD
echo $country -> IN

// Wrong result
extractNameAndCountry('BRY AIR [ASIA] PVT LTD [IN]');
echo $without -> BRY AIR
echo $country -> ASIA] PVT LTD [IN
```

I'm try other ways in http://rubular.com/ or https://regex101.com/ but I don't kwon how to extract only first concurrence at end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_match('~^(.*?)\s*\[([^][]*)]\s*$~u', $s, $match)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - any 0+ whitespaces
- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` chars
- `]` - a literal `]`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Ts9gV6):

```
$strs = ["BRY AIR PVT LTD [IN] ", "BRY AIR [ASIA] PVT LTD [IN]"];
foreach ($strs as $s) {
    if (preg_match('~^(.*?)\s*\[([^][]*)]\s*$~u', $s, $match)) {
        echo $match[1] . "<=>" . $match[2] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BRY AIR PVT LTD<=>IN
BRY AIR [ASIA] PVT LTD<=>IN
```

Note that you may